# Matlab 2018B Detect if a variable has changed from previous sampling

Tags: matlab

I came across `hasChanged(var_name)` to know if var_name changed from previous. I tried to implement in my matlab 2018b. Surprisingly it did not work saying not found?

Any idea how to implement it here?

[image]

Comment: It is part of the Stateflow Toolbox. Do you have it installed? https://www.mathworks.com/help/stateflow/ref/haschanged.html

Comment: @CrisLuengo So, to install this, do I have to completely uninstall the matlab and reinstall it with this package?

Comment: No, you can run the MATLAB installer again to add or remove toolboxes that you have a license for.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Don't mind, can you provide me the steps how to spot the matlab installer and do it. I will appreciate that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Ok. I found the add-on options in the Matlab. Which package do I have to install to get the `hasChanged()` function?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Solved. Thanks